# NotSupportedException in LINQ query with inner and outer joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have the following query with several inner and outer joins. The query create a new class that is not a part of Entity framework but a class that holds data for report:

```
from T6340 in PayOrders
from T6351 in POrderAccPDocLines.Where(x=> T6340.Id == x.PaymentDocId)
from T6321 in PaymentDocLines.Where(x=> T6351.PaymentDocId == x.PaymentDocId &&  
     T6351.Line ==  x.Line)
from T6125 in ItemBillPDocLines.Where(x =>T6321.PaymentDocId == x.PaymentDocId &&     
     T6321.Line == x.LineId).DefaultIfEmpty(null)
from T6126 in ItemBillStockPDocs.Where(x => T6125.BillId== x.ItemBillId && 
     T6125.PaymentDocId == x.PaymentDocId && T6125.LineId == x.PDocLineId &&  
     T6125.SplitNumber == x.PDocSplitNumber).DefaultIfEmpty(null)
from T6126_A in ItemBillStockPDocs.Where(x => T6125.BillId == x.ItemBillId && 
     T6125.PaymentDocId == x.PaymentDocId && T6125.LineId == x.PDocLineId && 
     T6125.SplitNumber == x.PDocSplitNumber).DefaultIfEmpty(null)
from T6201 in StockTransactions.Where(x => T6126.TransactionId == x.Id && 
     T6126.TransactionSubId == x.SubId).DefaultIfEmpty(null)
where T6125.BillId == billId && T6321.PaymentDoc.Canceled == 0
group new
{
 T6321,T6125,T6351,T6126_A,T6340,T6201
}
by new
{
 T6321_PaymentDocId = T6321.PaymentDocId,
 T6321.Line,
 T6321.CurrencyId,
 T6321.Amount,
 T6125,                                
 T6351.GLAccount,
 T6351.PaymentOrderAmount,
 T6321.PaymentDoc.ReferenceCode,
 T6126_Quantity = T6126_A.Quantity,
 T6126_A.TransactionId,
 T6126_A.TransactionSubId,
 T6351.PaymentOrderId,
 T6340.PayCurrency,
 T6126_A.TransactionSplitNumber
} into grouped
select new PaymentDataStore()
{
    ItemBillPaymentDocLine = grouped.Key.T6125,
    Currency = grouped.Key.CurrencyId,
    Amount = grouped.Key.Amount,
    PaymentDocumentId = grouped.Key.T6321_PaymentDocId,
    Approved = 0,
    Rate = 0,
    MaxExecutionDate = grouped.Max(x=>x.T6201.ExecutionDate),
    GLAccount = grouped.Key.GLAccount,
    PaymentOrderAmount = grouped.Key.PaymentOrderAmount,
    Constant1 = 0,
    ReferenceDocument = grouped.Key.ReferenceCode,
    Quantity = grouped.Key.T6126_Quantity,
    TransactionId = grouped.Key.TransactionId,
    TransactionSubId = grouped.Key.TransactionSubId,
    Constant2 = 0,
    PaymentOrder = grouped.Key.PaymentOrderId,
    PaymentCurrency = grouped.Key.PayCurrency,
    TransationSplitNumber = grouped.Key.TransactionSplitNumber
   }).ToList()
```

when I execute the query I'm getting an Exception:

```
NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 
'T6351_POrdAccPDocLine'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and 
Guid') are supported in this context.
```

I tried to find the cause of the exception with no luck.

Why do I keep getting exception?

**Edit: **

I changed the second line of the query to:

```
from T6340 in PayOrders
join T6351 in POrderAccPDocLines on T6340.Id equals T6351.PaymentDocId ...
```

Now I get the same exception on the T6321 entity. 
I guess thats the way to do (convert the statements to use joins) but I don't know how it can be done with outer join (lines 5-6 in the query) since I don't have the option of DefaultIfEmpty() when using join.

I'm banging my head for a while. Can you help me?

Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this line cannot be resolved: `MaxExecutionDate = grouped.Max(x=>x.T6201.ExecutionDate),` since that is inside the constructor of `PaymentDataStore` which is probably a model.

Comment: Nop, I commented the line and still the same exception.

Comment: The exception is most probably a result of your group by on the entity level `group new
{
 T6321,T6125,T6351,T6126_A,T6340,T6201
}` Try grouping by primitive types if that is an option. Also the generated sql is probably gigantic, because it will group by every field of every entity used in the group by. Perhaps [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a good idea to see what sql is produced. Please give only a minimum of the query that would produce  the exception and the classes/entities that are used in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is here:

```
by new
{
  ...
  T6125,
  ...
}
```

The LINQ to Entities engine needs to convert your expression to a SQL sentence, and it is not capable of doing so if you include a whole object (rather than a primitive type) in the expression.

Comment: No Luck. I removed the lines from the group by and the select statements and still the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

May this can help u ....

```
from po in payOrders
join pod in POrderAccPDocLines on po.Id equals pod.PaymentDocId
join pdl in PaymentDocLines on new { Id = pod.PaymentDocId, Line = pod.Line } equals  new { Id = pdl.PaymentDocId, Line = pdl.Line }
join ibdl in ItemBillPDocLines on new { Id = pdl.PaymentDocId, Line = pdl.Line } equals  new { Id = ibdl.PaymentDocId, Line = ibdl.Line } into ItemBill  //Outer Join
from ibdl in ItemBill.DefaultIfEmpty() //Outer Join
join.......
```